# react-native-jitsi-meet module not found

Tags: react-native, jitsi-meet

I am trying to install `Jitsi-Meet` plugin in my react-native project. I am trying to create a video/audio conference meetup feature in a website and I want to use react-native for the same purpose.

this is the plugin link.[react-native-jitsi-meet - npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jitsi-meet)

The plugin gets successfully installed in the package.json

[image]

But when I am trying to import in my `App.tsx` file, it shows me module not found

[image]

How can I import the plugin successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1- Something is Missings**

There is **missing** **index.js** file which is mendatory for npm packge. you can see in screenshot
[image]

-

**2- You need to perform these steps to resolve this package**

**Step 1:**

make index.js file at `node_modules/react-native-jitsi-meet/index.js`

**Step 2:**

and this add code in that index.js file

```
import { NativeModules, requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

export const JitsiMeetView = requireNativeComponent('RNJitsiMeetView');
export const JitsiMeetModule = NativeModules.RNJitsiMeetView;
const call = JitsiMeetModule.call;
const audioCall = JitsiMeetModule.audioCall;
JitsiMeetModule.call = (url, userInfo) => {
  userInfo = userInfo || {};
  call(url, userInfo);
}
JitsiMeetModule.audioCall = (url, userInfo) => {
  userInfo = userInfo || {};
  audioCall(url, userInfo);
}
export default JitsiMeetModule;
```

[image]

after these steps everything will be working

**Node:** you should automate these steps when we install any package by `npm` or `yarn`

we can use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to automate these steps

Comment: the project was in git. which i didn't make. that was a very dumb thinking from my side. however i resolved it before your comment. still i will upvote and accept it.

Comment: you can clone then perform these steps and make patch package then push again that will become the part of your project

Comment: I am still facing this issue. even after the fix