# App being crashed after adding the react-native-jitsi-meet library

Tags: react-native, jitsi

I'm trying to implement the video conference functionality by using the react-native-jitsi-meet library. But app is being crashed without showing any issue.

I have used added the package and implemented the android process for the **react version > 0.60** as mentioned in the document(https://github.com/skrafft/react-native-jitsi-meet) unable to find the issue. Haven't added any code in the **JS** file too.

I have tried [react-native-jitsi-meet module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338882/react-native-jitsi-meet-module-not-found) also but still the issue continues.

Comment: It is based on the node version you are using in your machine and issues that come with the Jitsi node dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

As it is specified in documentation we already changed the app.bundle as rename and it is bundling incorrectly so do this changes.
Remove the following file

```
android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

`npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/app.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ && cd android && ./gradlew` assembleDebug